# JSON/JSONB field support in Corda PostgreSQL

Tags: corda, corda-dlt

I am trying to implement JSON/JSONB in a persistence schema (PostgreSQL) and I was able to create a corresponding field using Liquibase script and with the help of  https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils.Currently, the issue which I am facing is that the JSON/JSONB not supported by H2 and all my unit test case are failing. Is there any work around to solve the issue? Also, is it possible to apply JSONPath based query filtering to  Vault Query?